# solr field specific query returns exact match for the whole field

Tags: solr

I'm just getting started with solr but thought this is somewhat counterintuitive.  Please help.

Two of my documents have author = "Rick Riordan".
When I run these queries:

**Rick**

> => returns 2 docs, good!

**author:Rick**

> => returns nothing.... why?

**author:"Rick Riordan"**

> => returns 2 docs.... looks like it assumes exact match.

Comment: show us your  schema.xml file

Comment: could you share the schema.xml ?

Comment: schema fragment:

      {
        "name":"author",
        "type":"strings"},

Comment: it was created automatically.  looks like "strings" type is defined as       {
        "name":"strings",
        "class":"solr.StrField",
        "sortMissingLast":true,
        "multiValued":true},

Comment: Type-->Strings. There is a fieldtype tag associated with strings. Paste that in here

Comment: "fieldTypes":[{
        "name":"ancestor_path",
        "class":"solr.TextField",
        "indexAnalyzer":{
          "tokenizer":{
            "class":"solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"}},
        "queryAnalyzer":{
          "tokenizer":{
            "class":"solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory",
            "delimiter":"/"}}},
      {
        "name":"binary",
        "class":"solr.BinaryField"}, ...

Comment: @user1576462 you should add additional information to the question instead of as comments, so it will be easily available to all user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as a fieldType.

> It'll do the following-
>   1. Generate tokens on white spaces. So that you can either search on individual  words or whole word.
>   2. It will remove duplicate indexes reducing index size.

```
<fieldType name="strings" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!--  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>-->
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the field Type for your Field author.   Re-index the same and Try Searching the same.

```
<fieldType>
<analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

fire your query on a field name like below

```
q=:author:Rick
```